# Slack Outgoing Webhook to Incoming Webhook in MS Teams

Tags: slack, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to connect a Slack channel to Teams and to forward all messages to teams. I thought it would be as easy as using an outgoing webhook in Slack and and incoming webhook in Teams. However nothing is ever sent to Teams. Is this even possible without the use of some automation tool like Zapier or IFTTT?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are probably a *bunch* of reasons this is not working - I can imagine there could be authentication issues, and also that the structure of the data coming *from* slack is unlikely to be what Teams can consume 100% as is. Basically, you're going to need some kind of intermediary, like perhaps an Azure Function or AWS Lambda (unless Zapier/IFTTT can offer something out of the box for this). Power Automate could be another option, incidentally.

As another option, you could look to a 3rd party that does something like this already, like [m.io](https://m.io/) (Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with them, or even experience with their platform, I'm just aware of the existence of their tool).

With regards docs, have a look at [Outgoing Webhooks for Slack](https://api.slack.com/legacy/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks) and [Incoming Webhooks for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using). Even from the docs, you can see the format/structure is *very* different, so it's just a case of a small Cloud function to map input <-> output.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried Power Automate, but it only supports forwarding files for now.
Are you aware of any documentation regarding webhooks format in teams and slack. For now I was asuming it is an open standard...
I had a look at m.io, but it is complete overkill for what I'm trying to solve. I have to forward 20 messages a day from one Slack channel to one Teams channel.
We are on Google Cloud, so Cloud functions could be an option, but I can't find a good starting point nowhere. Not many code examples on github...

Comment: ah ok, so this is reasonably isolated, not like ALL TEAMS for the whole company. In that case, Cloud functions, if you've got access to that (skills etc.) is probably fine (I've not used them, but I assume they're pretty much the equivalent of Azure Functions). I've updated the original answer above with links to get you started.

Comment: Thanks I've ended up building a Slack app and not using outgoing webhooks. They are very limited and didn't forward all the messages.

Comment: ok. How did you send to Teams in the end? Via it's incoming webhook option?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Basically it's a Slack App sending data via the events api to a Google Cloud Functions python script. There the data is formatted for Teams and sent to a Teams webhook.